# Не стартует сервер джанго

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Ввожу в командной строке

```
python manage.py runserver
```

затем на пол-секунды открывается консолька и на ней:

```
can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or dictionary.
```

В чем может быть проблема?
Django - 1.6.4, Python - 3.3

Comment: Помогла [эта ссылка](https://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8#:~:text=%2Fd%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%20%D0%B8,(%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%2C%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D

Answer (score 1):

```
cd %project dir% && python manage.py runserver
```

или

```
chmod +x manage.py  
./manage.py runserver
```

или еще 100500 вариантов почему питон не видит твой manage.py
p.s: мысли читать не умеем

Comment: Я учусь как использовать питон в веб, я пытаюсь запустить сервер как показано тут: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l_django/ 
P.S:То, что вы написали, к сожалению, не помогло.

Answer (score -1):

Для старта сервера необходимо, **находясь в корневой директории проекта**, выполнить команду: `python manage.py runserver`.